# What would be the worst-case complexity of the following implementation? Can it be improved by any other way?

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, time-complexity

We have been provided an array with **N** integers. We need to select atleast **K** integers from the array, with each element having integer values between an upper bound **MAX** and lower bound **MIN**, bounds inclusive.

The task at hand is to determine how many combinations can be created from the list.

My first go at the problem was a naïve approach (I assumed itertools would have been a cop-out):

```
def n_length_combo(iterable, r):
    char = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(char)
    if r > n:
        return
    index = list(range(r))
    yield tuple(char[i] for i in index)
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if index[i] != i + n - r:
                break
        else:
            return
        index[i] += 1
        for j in range(i + 1, r):
            index[j] = index[j-1] + 1
        yield tuple(char[i] for i in index)


temp_list = []
for i in range(len(arr)):
    if arr[i] >= MIN and arr[i] <= MAX:
        temp_list.append(arr[i])

combo = []
for n in range(K, len(temp_list)+1):
    combo.extend([x for x in n_length_combo(temp_list, n)])

print(len(combo))
```

I realized soon after that this would be inefficient since the combinations weren't required, just the number of combinations possible.

I came up with this solution (I assumed importing math would be allowed, as opposed to directly importing nCr):

```
from math import gcd

temp_list = []
for i in range(len(arr)):
    if arr[i] >= MIN and arr[i] <= MAX:
        temp_list.append(arr[i])

def NcR(n, r):
    p = 1
    k = 1
    if (n - r < r):
        r = n - r
    if (r != 0):
        while (r):
            p *= n
            k *= r
            m = gcd(p, k)
            p //= m
            k //= m
            n -= 1
            r -= 1
    else:
        p = 1
    return p

sum = 0
for i in range(K, len(temp_list)+1):
    sum = sum + NcR(len(temp_list),i)

print (sum)
```

A friend suggested that the sum of the binomial expansion for <sup>n</sup>C<sub>r</sub> (from 0 to n) is 2<sup>n</sup> (using bit shift, 1<<n). Also, it has a max value at *r=n/2*. Would it be possible to leverage these facts and come up with a better implementation? I don't know the worst-case complexities of either algorithms.

P.S. [The question was probably pulled from this site](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/2-team-formation-2-fc-codelona-trying-assemble-team-roster-available-players-minimum-numbe-q75768271)

Comment: Your reasoning seems right. Let's say there are M elements in original array which meet the range requirements. Then you sum nCr(M,i) for i=K to M. It's true that sum nCr(n,i) for i=0  to n is 2^n but it doesn't help much in your case. There is a closed form solution which involves the hypergeometric function F, but then you'd have to code that as well as nCr function. Ie, nCr(M,K) * F(1, K-M; K+1; -1)

Comment: @JohnD I'm confused as to how the hypergeometric function will help here (probably because this is the first time I've heard of it). Will you be able to explain how it would help? I realize that abs(z) has to be <1, or else we will delve into the complex plane, and the whole scenario seems _troubling_ to me.

Comment: I think you already have the best approach. I mentioned that formula because you were interested in other approaches. The fomula does not require a loop to get the sum, it gives you the sum directly. But unfortunately you have to evaluate the hypergeometric function to get it, which  is difficult. See this link: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+ncr%28m%2Ci%29+for+i%3Dk%2Cm